# How can I reach tmux session that is after 9 digits

Tags: tmux

I usually search for a session on tmux but don’t know how to hit `M-a` using my keyboard.

[image]

Comment: The M signifies the Meta key, usually implemented through the `alt` key on modern keyboards. Try alt+a/b/c. On a macbook the options key is usually the one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key

Answer (score 1):

That's the Meta modifier, it's usually mapped to Alt.

Alt+a should work.

Comment: how can i modify the meta modifier?

Comment: If you're talking system-wide, then you can set a shortcut from whatever key you want to alt. This will obviously cause conflict with other shortcuts. If you're talking about just for tmux, then I'm not that experienced with configuring tmux. I'm sure you'll find a solution on google